# Issue with Google Tag Manager Debug Mode

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have tried implementing Google Tag Manager for my blog (Blogger). When I try to preview the tag implementation using Preview and Debug Mode, I am unable to see the Debug Mode. The Debug mode appears briefly while the blog is being loaded but then vanishes once the blog is loaded.

Any suggestions on how to rectify this issue will be deeply appreciated.

Please find below my Google Tag Manager Code:

```
 <body>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe height='0' src='//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX' style='display:none;visibility:hidden' width='0'/></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({&#39;gtm.start&#39;:
new Date().getTime(),event:&#39;gtm.js&#39;});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=&#39;dataLayer&#39;?&#39;&amp;l=&#39;+l:&#39;&#39;;j.async=true;j.src=
&#39;//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=&#39;+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,&#39;script&#39;,&#39;dataLayer&#39;,&#39;GTM-XXXXX&#39;);</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: If that's your exact GTM container code, then at least you would need to convert the HTML entities. For example, "&#39;" converts to a single quote, so all these would need to be converted.

Comment: Also, make sure no script or ad blocking browser add-ons are running (e.g., uBlock Origin, AdBlock, Adblock Plus etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestions from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602840/issue-with-google-tag-manager-debug-mode?rq=1#comment56954520_34602840), you need to convert the HTML entities. For example, "'" converts to a single quote, so all these would need to be converted. Also  make sure no script or ad blocking browser add-ons are running (e.g., uBlock Origin, AdBlock, Adblock Plus etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [Quick Start Guide page](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) for Google Tag Manager. The code should look like:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```